# Error launching Redhat MTA plugin configuration from IntelliJ

Tags: java, jboss, migration, redhat, intellij-plugin

This is the configuration (I attach only selected options)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I launch, I have this error

[image]

I have tried to search this error online and in the documentation; I've also tried to change Java version, but without success. The other options in the configuration doesn't seems to help. Do you know how I can solve?